# JSON to CSV Schema

Tags: json, csv, schema

I have some JSON data structures of bank accounts information that I export as CSV files in order to be opened up in Microsoft Excel. The JSON for each account is:

```
{
  "apy": 2.0,
  "product_type": "Investors Checking",
  "features":  {
    "ATM_FEES": "Refunded",
    "ATM_CARD_AVAILABLE": "Yes",
    "SIMPLY_MAINTAIN_A_MONTHLY_BALANCE_OF": "$10,000"
  },
  "min_investment": "",
  "max_investment": 20000,
  "institution_type": "Credit Union",
  "institution_num": 11307,
  "institution": "Apple Federal Credit Union"
}
```

I can export it fine with columns for everything except the "features" dictionary. That ends up as a column containing the object:

```
{
  "ATM_FEES": "Refunded",
  "ATM_CARD_AVAILABLE": "Yes",
  "SIMPLY_MAINTAIN_A_MONTHLY_BALANCE_OF": "$10,000"
}
```

For any given bank, the features dict can be any arbitrary length with a variety of features. I mostly have experience with document-oriented databases (MongoDB).

How should I construct a relational schema for the same data?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a CSV format? or are you looking to create a relational DB Schema to store the information (in a database/not CSV)? CSV is just a flat file, and relational data concepts are not relevant.

Comment: Yes its going to eventually end up in a relation database (which I have little experience with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the CSV and relational structure don't match. CSV can have arbitrary number of fields with each feature as a separate column. In a relation database you would do that differently. I would suggest a table for the basic data, and one for the features. Something like this:

table BANK_ACCOUNT_INFO:

- ID
- apy
- product_type
- min_investment
- max_investment
- institution_type
- institution_num
- institution

table BANK_ACCOUNT_FEATURES:

- ID
- BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
- FEATURE_NAME
- FEATURE_VALUE

1 record in the basic table can be related to several records in the features table.

Comment: I see that makes much more senses now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
def headers:
    keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | if   .[$k]|type == "object" then (.[$k]|headers)
    else $k
    end
;

def data:
    keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | if   .[$k]|type == "object" then (.[$k]|data)
    else .[$k]
    end
;

  (.[0] | [headers])
, (.[]  | [data])
| @csv
```

If `filter.jq` contains this filter and `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
$ jq -Mrs -f filter.jq data.json
```

will produce

```
"apy","product_type","ATM_FEES","ATM_CARD_AVAILABLE","SIMPLY_MAINTAIN_A_MONTHLY_BALANCE_OF","min_investment","max_investment","institution_type","institution_num","institution"
2,"Investors Checking","Refunded","Yes","$10,000","",20000,"Credit Union",11307,"Apple Federal Credit Union"
```